# gain performance by replacing boost::unordered_map string-key with vector of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, performance, hash, smart-pointers

I would like to create an unordered_map where the key is a vector / array of shared_ptr.
Currently, I use a string-key that is created from pointed objects' string identifiers and it seems slow.
Is there a way to use either a vector of shared_ptr or a hash of such a vector as key?

Reading is more important than writing, as I have roughly 18 times more reads than writes. (current benchmark: 7 million writes to dict, 130 million reads)

As I'm new to C++, and especially to performance / memory and optimization, I attach the full info of what I'm doing below including rough pseudo-code.

---

**Problem setting:**

In my code I am creating the product of a vector of graphs.
This means, that the resulting graph `G = G1 * G2 * G3 * ...` is contains all combinations of nodes of the operands and the transitions between each node.

Thus, what I do is that I create all combinations of nodes from the operands and collect them in a vector of vectors. These are then combined to a vector of composite nodes.

Subsequently I create the ("unsynchronized") edges of the graph like so:

```
G1 : (n11) –-> (n12)
G2 : (n21) --> (n22)
G = G1 * G2

G: 
(n11,n21) --> (n12,n21)
    |             |
    |             |
    V             V
(n11,n22) --> (n12,n22)
```

Note: There is no "synchronized" edge from `(n11,n21)` to `(n12,n22)`

**Magnitude & Problem**
I'm combining some 10 graphs with up to 10 nodes each. My current benchmark creates 7'000'000 nodes and >130'000'000 edges (requiring > 100GB memory).

I am already happy with what I got. However, I used Inspector (on Mac Big Sur) to check if I have any significant performance issues and saw that in my `create_product` routine roughly 20% of the time is spent in the unordered_map's `.at(...)` routine.

I take that string-keys are low-performing and ideally I would replace them with the vector / array of pointers or a hash thereof.

---

Rough code example:

```
// info: each node has a name field
vector<vector<shared_ptr<Node>>> node_combinations = get_combinations(); /* function to create the combinations */

// info: name of composite is a comma-separated join of the subnode-names 
 e.g. name_n1,name_n2,name_n3
// info: CompositeNodes store the vector<shared_ptr<Node>> of the nodes they were created from
vector<shared_ptr<CompositeNode>> composites = get_composites(combinations); /* turns each "inside" vector into a composite node */


// create a map to find the composite node by its name
// this is actually created in the get_combinations() routine right away...
boost::unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<CompositeNode>> name_to_node;
for(auto &comp : composites) {
    name_to_node[comp->name] = comp;
}

// create edges ... improve below here

for(const auto &compnode : composed_states) {
    for(const auto &subnode : compnode->subnodes) {
        for(const auto &edge : subnode->edges) {
            // get the name of target
            string target_name;
            for(auto &subnode_target : compnode->subnodes) {
                if(substate == subtargetstate) { // if it's the current node, then replace with the target
                {
                    target_name.append(edge.target->name);
                }
                else  // otherwise the the name
                {
                    target_name.append(subnode_target->name); 
                }
                target_name.append(",");
            }

            shared_ptr<CompositeNode> target = name_to_node.at(target_name);

            /* code to create the edge from subnode to target */
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Currently, I use a string-key that is created from pointed objects' string identifiers and it seems slow" Did you already try to replace that keying with simpler types (size_t)? Do you really need the items to be unique within your container?

Comment: @Secundi nodes have a string name which is currently the only "unique" element. Indeed it would be interesting to replace within a graph the identifier with a size_t in the long run, but currently I am stuck with strings.

Comment: My experience is, that (std::) string keying is often misused as an inapproriate (fast developed though) first solution. Remember that not only the string parsing is relevant but surely also the overhead of std::string's construction/copy construction. For smaller strings, small string optimization might be able to absorb things here up to a certain degree but I think, that due to paths, that won't change that much here.

Comment: Exactly, string is not ideal and I use it because it kinda works. What I would like to do is to  use `vector<shared_ptr<Node>>` as key, but I'm not sure how to do so. I guess I'll have to somehow hash each shared_ptr and then combine the hashes (all in a deterministic way).